# How can I make the id field be hidden and assign itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

A user is authorized and wants to create a comment. When creating a new post, there is form with one field: `post`. The other field is hidden (it's in model Comment.rb). How can I assign the id of the user in the following def, so that the comment text and user_id are both saved?

**comment/view**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :user_id %> (this line should hide and id should assign itself)
    <%= f.input :text %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**sessions. controller**

```
 def create
      user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
      if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to admin_url
      else
        redirect_to login_url, alert: "Неправильный логин или пароль!"
    end

  end
```

**Comments_controller**

```
def create
    @user = User.all
    @comment = Comment.all
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Hey you should remove the line `@comment = Comment.all` in the create action of the comments_controller because it retrieves all the comments but you don't need it here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the `user_id` out of the form. Instead, in the controller, write:

```
 def create
   @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) #whoever the logged in user is
   @comment = @user.comments.build(comment_params)
   respond_to do |format|
     if @comment.save
       format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
       format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @comment }
     else
       format.html { render action: 'new' }
       format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
  end
 end
```

Also, make sure that your user model `has_many` comments.

Comment: A tip for you Joe Pym: while editing your answer, you can select the code piece and use `ctrl+k` in order to format it in a code block

Comment: undefined local variable or method `current_user'

Comment: Help me, please! undefined local variable or method `current_user'

Comment: Cat - I updated. You'll usually want to do User.find(session[:user_id]) as part of a current_user method on ApplicationController, to handle logged in users better.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the field by doing simply this

```
<%=f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => "its_value" %>
```

so it will be something like

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id , :value => @user.id %>      
 <%= f.input :text %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```